# How to purposely delay an AJAX response while testing with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a React component that mimics the "link preview" feature that most modern social media sites have. You type in a link and it fetches the image, title, etc...

[image]

I do this by having the React component make an AJAX call back to my server to fetch the URL preview data.

While it's fetching I show an intermediate "loading" state (i.e. some loading icon or spinning wheel)

The relevant React snippet looks like

```
this.setState({ isLoadingAttachment: true })

return $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: some_url,
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
}).success(function(response){
  // Succesful! Do Success stuff
  component.setState({ isLoadingAttachment: false })
}).error(function(response) {
  // Uh oh! Handle failure stuff
  component.setState({ isLoadingAttachment: false })
});
```

Note how the `isLoadingAttachment` state variable is only valid for a brief second while the server is doing the fetching. Both the success and error scenarios immediately disable it.

I'd like to test some functionality during my "loading" state with my Capybara feature specs. I've mocked all the web calls and the data to be returned by the server, but it all happens so quickly that it passes through the "loading" state before I can even run any `expect()..` statement on it. I also purposely don't call `wait_for_ajax` so the page will go ahead without waiting for the ajax, but it's still too fast.

Lastly I also tried purposefully delaying the server call by 1.0 second, but that didn't work either. I assume because the whole thing is single threaded somehow?

```
# `foo` is an arbitrary method called during the server-side execution
allow_any_instance_of(MyController).
  to receive(:foo) { sleep(1.0) }.and_call_original
```

Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara starts up the app server in a different thread than the tests, however if you're using the default `Capybara.server` setting you may have issues with your app calling back to itself since it uses webrick by default.  Instead you should specify `Capybara.server = :puma`.  Beyond that, mocking responses is generally a bad idea in feature specs (which are generally meant to be end-to-end tests) since it means you're not actually testing your apps code the way it would run in production anymore.  A better solution is to use something like `puffing-billy` - https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy - to mock web responses outside of your apps code which would allow you to do something like

```
proxy.stub('https://example.com/proc/').and_return(Proc.new { |params, headers, body|
  sleep 2
  { :text => "Your results"}
})
```

Comment: Thanks! One other followup - what makes `puma` a better choice for the server than `webrick` here? I would have thought the server is irrelevant since they both produce the same sort of response

Comment: @user2490003 `puma` by default is multithreaded and will handle multiple simultaneous requests (like one request to your app that is making another request back to the same app) - Also 99% sure you're not using webrick in production, maybe you're using puma?  and it's best to make the test env match production as much as possible.

Comment: You are correct, i'm using Puma in Production. Thanks for explaining!